# Java 8 type inference error

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I tried to generalize my map transposing method using Java 8 stream. Here is the code

```
public static <K, V> Map<V, Collection<K>> trans(Map<K, Collection<V>> map,
                                                     Function<? super K, ? extends V> f,
                                                     Function<? super V, ? extends K> g) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .map(l -> {
                            V iK = f.apply(e.getKey());
                            K iV = g.apply(l);
                            return Tuple2.of(iK, iV);
                        }))
                .collect(groupingBy(Tuple2::getT2, mapping(Tuple2::getT1, toCollection(LinkedList::new))));
    }

public class Tuple2<T1, T2> {

    private final T1 t1;
    private final T2 t2;

    public static <T1, T2> Tuple2<T1, T2> of(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        return new Tuple2<>(t1, t2);
    }

    // constructor and getters omitted
}
```

But I got this error message

```
Error:(66, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: V
    lower bounds: K
```

What do I have to change for it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you actually transpose the values as keys and vice-versae to your original input, but since you apply functions that preserves the same key value types as in the original map, you end up with a `Stream<Tuple2<V, K>>` after your flatmap operation, so the collect returns a `Map<K, Collection<V>>` again.

So the method header should be:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, Collection<V>> trans(Map<K, Collection<V>> map,
                                                 Function<? super K, ? extends V> f,
                                                 Function<? super V, ? extends K> g)
```

Comment: Thank you. I just figured it out that I don't have to swap the key/value twice because the mappers already did.